# Need a hint to start prove an inequality

Tags: inequality

wan't know how to start this problem, tried to multiply by $\sqrt{n}$, but it does not work. Can someone help me with that? Thanks. Here is the inequality. 
$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263115/proof-of-inequality-2-sqrtn1-sqrtn-frac1-sqrtn-2-sqrtn, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139563/proof-by-induction-2-sqrtn1-sqrtn-frac1-sqrtn-2-sqrtn

Comment: hint: use induction

Comment: hint: use integration on $1/\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\\
\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}=(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 5):

By MVT,

$$\sqrt {n}-\sqrt {n-1}=\frac {1}{2\sqrt {c}} $$

$$\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt {n}=\frac {1}{2\sqrt {d}} $$
with $$n-1 <c <n<d <n+1 . $$