# Properties of the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question has two parts

> Let $x_n$ be a sequence where $x_n=\sqrt{n}$
>
> a) Is $\{x_n\}$ a contractive sequence?
>
> b) Prove that $\frac{|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|}{|x_{n+1}-x_n|}=\frac{|\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}|}{|\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}|}<1$ for all n.

Notes:

A) $\{x_n\}$ has no upper bound since for any possible integer $q$, there is a greater integer (e.g. $\sqrt{(q+1)^2}>\sqrt{q}$). If $\{x_n\}$  was contractive, it would also be Cauchy and converge (as $\mathbb{R}$ is complete). Therefore it would be bounded, thus we have a contradiction so $\{x_n\}$ is not contractive.

B) Simply graphing $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ shows that it is a decreasing sequence. But I am not sure how to prove so using algebra.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Added notes to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Square Root Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRootInequality.html),

$$\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1} < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} < \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$$

Therefore,

$${\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1} \over \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} < 1$$

---

See the following for a proof of the inequality:

[Proof of inequality $2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2(\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1})$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263115/proof-of-inequality-2-sqrtn1-sqrtn-frac1-sqrtn-2-sqrtn)

Comment: Thank you for the answering part B. However how does the statement ${\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1} \over \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} < 1$ show that $x_n$ is contractive. I feel like there is something I am missing.

Comment: @NhG I'm sorry, you are correct. It is not contractive.